# can you use blight spray on all edible and ornamental trees, shrubs and bushes

Tags: trees, diseases, fungus

At first, it was just my pear trees, then it seems everything has it.  It looks like brown spots that turn the leaves yellow.  But there are holes and half eaten leaves also.  Some leaves such as my hibiscus look like the chlorofil has been sucked out of part of the leaf..  Some look like leafrollers but no worms inside.  It is confusing.  What can I do about it?  I have tried Diematious Earth, neem oil and dishwashing soap, and am about to try fire blight spray for pears.  Any sugesstions?

Comment: Fireblight is specific to plants in the Rosaceae family only, so if you have lots of plants with problems, unless they're all members of that family, it won't be fireblight. We need information on and images of affected plants (in separate questions per plant) if you want advice as to what might be wrong - its entirely possible for plants in gardens to have a wide range of problems unrelated to one another,, and indiscriminately spraying with anything without identifying the problem is not advisable.

Comment: And fungal infections can not be treated after the infection with fungicide (exception is powdery mildew).  Diatomaceous earth is sharp shards used for deterring slugs and snails.  Leaf rollers are insects that grow up and sometimes fly away sometimes crawl away.  The most important rule of all is to know exactly what insect or disease you have BEFORE ever throwing pesticides willy nilly at your problems.  This will get you in far bigger problems.  Pesticides, herbicides, fungicides, miticides are bandaids for problems we humans caused.  They rarely work.